# Jboss 7.1.1 + Windows 7 (64 bit) + JDK 7 1.7.07 (64) fails to start

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, jboss

I have a default download of [jboss 7.1.1](http://download.jboss.org/jbossas/7.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip) that resides on my windows 7 system. I have the following set in my **system** environment variables and both were added to the **Path** variable:

```
JBOSS_HOME=C:\jboss-7.1.1\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final  
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07
```

When I run from an **Administrator** console I get the following output:

```
C:\jboss-7.1.1\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>standalone.bat
Calling "C:\jboss-7.1.1\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
```

No error messages and no other feedback.  What is causing the complete lack of error message and lack of feedback?

Comment: I vaguely remember some bugs with early Java 1.7 versions (and I'm not even sure). Just in case, have you tried the latest Java version?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos holy jeebus didnt realize i was 40 revisions behind.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos and that was exactly the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure when JRE 7 became compatible, but if anyone else comes along it does at least work with `JRE 7u45` .  This allows JBOSS to correctly start.